# Best practice for null testing

Tags: c#, .net

When working with objects you're not sure are null or not, what is the best practice?

```
object o = SomeMethodReturningAnObjectOrNull();
```

Is it better to check `o` like this:

```
if (o != null)
{
    //do something usefull
}
```

Or to make a try catch:

```
try
{
    //do something usefull
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{

}
```

If it depends on the situation, what is the advantage of one or the other?

Comment: Obviously check for null. Why this question in first place? Btw question is subjective and no definite answer.

Comment: A value being `null` is not **exceptional**. It is something you can test for, so do so.

Comment: `NullReferenceException` means something went wrong (trying to reference `null` is a bug simply), so it is something different that some variable is `null`.